# How to write one trigger to all table to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote a trigger which fires when update on `Employee` table.

When trigger fires it insert new record to `Transact` table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [PROJECTS].[after_updateEmployee] ON [PROJECTS].[Employee]
AFTER  UPDATE
AS DECLARE @tablen varchar(30) , @modyfire  varchar(15),@modyfied_date datetime,@columname   varchar(20),@action varchar(6)
SET @tablen ='Employee'
set @modyfire =(SELECT SYSTEM_USER)
set @modyfied_date =(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
SET @columname = (SELECT TOP 1 E_id  FROM PROJECTS.Employee ORDER BY RV DESC)
set @action ='UPDATE'
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PROJECTS.Transact values(@tablen,@modyfire,@modyfied_date,@columname,@action)
END
```

I have more tables in my database.So is there any way to use this trigger for all tables in my database.

Thank You.

Comment: Triggers are defined **on a table** - there's no concept of something like global triggers. If you want a trigger on 10 tables, you'll have to write 10 trigger - one on each table.

Comment: If your triggers follow a pattern - which I assume yours do - you should be able to generate a script by running `select` statements over the `information_schema` and then applying the triggers automatically (by running the script).

Comment: Adding to previous comments - you can automate it for newly created tables by creating a DDL trigger that will add appropriate trigger to new table.

Comment: There are two big warning signs when it comes to SQL Server triggers. The first is if the trigger assumes that only a single row has been inserted/updated/deleted. The second is if the trigger doesn't contain any references to the `inserted` and/or `deleted` pseudo-tables. This trigger appears to have both issues.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277748/how-use-inserted-deleted-table-in-stored-procedure) answer you can try the following:

Create new type as a table which contains object's id and table:

```
create type table_rows as table
(
    row_id      uniqueidentifier not null,  -- deleted object id
    table_name  varchar(50) not null        -- object's table
);
```

This function logs every deleted object in `auto_log` table:

```
create procedure mark_as_deleted(@r as table_rows readonly) as
begin
    insert into auto_log (id, row_id, table_name, t_deleted, editor)
        select NEWID(), row_id, table_name, getdate(), current_user from @r
end
```

And finally the trigger which must applied to each table:

```
create trigger on_delete_object on [dbo].[object]
instead of delete as
begin
    declare @table table_rows

    insert into @table
        select id, object_schema_name(parent_id) + '.' + object_name(parent_id)
        from deleted
        join sys.triggers on object_id = @@PROCID

    -- Do what ever you need with deleted data
    exec mark_as_deleted @table
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that all the triggers will be familiar and the code used to work with deleted data is placed in the separate procedure