# How use inserted\deleted table in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I creating triggers for several tables. The triggers have same logic. I will want to use a common stored procedure.
But I don't know how work with **inserted** and **deleted** table.

example:

```
SET @FiledId = (SELECT FiledId FROM inserted)
begin tran
   update table with (serializable) set DateVersion = GETDATE()
   where FiledId = @FiledId

   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
      insert table (FiledId) values (@FiledId)
   end
commit tran
```

Comment: You can't. the pseudo-tables are only available directly in triggers. And your code is broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or multiple rows - `SET @FiledId = (SELECT FiledId FROM inserted)` is selecting a value from *one* of those rows and ignoring the others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store the inserted / deleted values from triggers, and pass it across to the proc. e.g., if all you need in your proc is the UNIQUE `FileID's`:

```
CREATE TYPE FileIds AS TABLE
(
    FileId INT
);

-- Create the proc to use the type as a TVP
CREATE PROC commonProc(@FileIds AS FileIds READONLY)
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE at
            SET at.DateVersion = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM ATable at
            JOIN @FileIds fi
            ON at.FileID = fi.FileID;
    END
```

And then pass the inserted / deleted ids from the trigger, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON SomeTable FOR INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FileIds FileIDs;
        INSERT INTO @FileIds(FileID)
            SELECT DISTINCT FileID FROM INSERTED;
        EXEC commonProc @FileIds;
    END;
```

Comment: Once you have the Type and proc in place, its 3 LOC per trigger, which you say you already have ?

Comment: My 2 cents: Beware that triggers can be hard to debug and putting too much logic in them is bound to get you into trouble down the road.

Answer (score 5):

You can

```
select * into #Inserted from inserted
select * into #Deleted from deleted
```

and then

use these two temp tables in your stored proc

Answer (score 0):

The tables inserted and deleted are only available inside the trigger. You can only use them in run-time. They will then contain the affected rows.

Also, your code might not work as expected if there is not exactly one row inserted.

Comment: Maybe Can I pass the table in a parameter ?

Comment: Sorry, not to a trigger. But perhaps you cold use dynamic sql to do what you want.